# Create dictionary from an array of objects using property of object as key for the dictionary?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

With Swift is it possible to create a dictionary of [String:[Object]] from an array of objects [Object] using a property of those objects as the String key for the dictionary using swift's "map"?

```
class Contact:NSObject {

   var id:String = ""
   var name:String = ""
   var phone:String = ""

   init(id:String, name:String, phone:String){
      self.id = id
      self.name = name
      self.phone = phone
   }

}

var contactsArray:[Contact]
var contactsDict:[String:Contact]

contactsDict = (contactsArray as Array).map { ...WHAT GOES HERE... }
```

Comment: Calling map on an array returns another array, so no

Comment: You may use `forEach` and then populate a dictionary with the values. `map` returns an array - as @dan already pointed out.

Comment: If there is a better way than using "map" im open to that.

Comment: Currently i'm just looping over the items in the array and adding them that way. I just hoped there was a more concise solution.

Comment: Why is your `contactsDict` has `[String: [Contact]]`. Shouldn't it be `[String: Contact]`. And what field to use for the key of dictionary?

Comment: Yes your right it should be [String:Contact] I miss  typed it when i wrote the question. and im using the "id" property of the Contact object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you want to use `id` as the key for the dictionary:

```
var contactsArray = [Contact]()
// add to contactsArray

var contactsDict = [String: Contact]()
contactsArray.forEach {
    contactsDict[$0.id] = $0
}
```

The difference between `map` and `forEach` is that `map` returns an array. `forEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks the forEach was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this via `reduce` in a one-line functional-style code:

```
let contactsDict = contactsArray.reduce([String:Contact]()) { var d = $0; d[$1.id] = $1; return d; }
```

This also keeps `contactsDict` immutable, which is the preferred way to handle variables in Swift.

Or, if you want to get fancy, you can overload the `+` operator for dictionaries, and make use of that:

```
func +<K,V>(lhs: [K:V], rhs: Contact) -> [K:V] {
    var result = lhs
    result[rhs.0] = rhs.1
    return result
}

let contactsDict = contacts.reduce([String:Contact]()) { $0 + ($1.id, $1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

There's now a direct way to do this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init

It's an initializer for Dictionary that lets you return a string key for each element in a Collection that specifies how it should be grouped in the resulting Dictionary.

Comment: The following link doesn't exist.

Comment: I updated the link above to one that works for this initializer mentioned by @Josh